# How to bifurcate dictionary data that contain particular string name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my Application i got the data in MutableDictionary like this,

```
 ApproverDetails:(
    {
    "APPROVER_ID" = "5000";
    "APPROVER_USER_NAME" = "38400 user";
    "END_DATE" = "12/29/10";
    "START_DATE" = "12/14/10";
    "SUBSTITUTE_ID" = SUPERVISOR;
    "SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME" = "ACCESS ONLY";
    },
    {
    "APPROVER_ID" = "6000";
    "APPROVER_USER_NAME" = "ACCESS ONLY";
    "END_DATE" = "12/31/10";
    "START_DATE" = "12/15/10";
    "SUBSTITUTE_ID" = SSEEMON;
    "SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME" = "Sunil Seemon";
    },
    {
    "APPROVER_ID" = "7000";
    "APPROVER_USER_NAME" = mit;
    "END_DATE" = "11/22/10";
    "START_DATE" = "11/09/10";
    "SUBSTITUTE_ID" = 2000;
    "SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME" = mitul;
   }
 )
```

From above dictionary i want bifurcate data by key **"Approved_User_Name" starting with "ACC"**

and get bifurcated data into other Array.

Please suggest me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *bifurcateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
for (NSDictionary *temp in ApproverDetails) {
    NSString *string=[temp objectForKey:@"APPROVER_USER_NAME"];
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"ACC"].location!=NSNotFound && [string rangeOfString:@"ACC"].location==0 ) {
        [bifurcateArray addObject:temp];
    }
}
NSLog(@"bifurcated data : %@",bifurcateArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSPredicate to get data as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"APPROVER_USER_NAME BEGINSWITH[cd] ACC"];
searchResults = [[ApproverDetails filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: And get everything else by filtering on the inverse of the same predicate. Not super efficient since it has to pass through the array twice, but unless you have huge data or you're doing this many times a second that shouldn't matter.